# Cómo uso el paste sólo para algunas filas?

Tags: r, data

Tengo un df que tiene una columna ID:

```
ID   
10152
10425
10458
552226
482563
```

Necesito anteponer un 0 sólo a las tres primeras filas. He pensado en usar algo del tipo `df$ID<-paste0("0",df$ID)`, pero no sé cómo indicarle que sólo lo haga con las 3 primeras filas. He intentado poniendo

```
df$ID<-paste0("0",df$ID, [1:3,]) 
df$ID<-paste0("0",df$ID)[1:3,]
```

Pero ninguno funciona....

También me sucede otra cosa y es que al visualizar mi df en la consola, los números de una columna en particular están de manera exponencial. El problema es que debo hacer un `merge` usando dicha columna con otro df, en el que los datos si se ven con todos los dígitos completos. Habría algún problema con el `merge`?

Comment: `df$ID[1:3] <- paste0("0",def$ID)`, esto transformará la columna `ID` de numérica a character, seguramente con esto también resuelvas el problema de la notación exponencial.

Comment: Para hacer un `merge` es **mejor** que sean cadenas de caracteres, porque si `ID` es de coma flotante la comparación puede dar resultados inconsistentes. Para hacer joins con unidades territoriales me encuentro con frecuencia con este problema y la solución general que uso es normalizar el largo de las variables de empate agregando 0 con la función `sprintf`. En tu caso `df$ID <- sprintf("%06d", ID)`, que *siempre* te va a regresar cadenas de largo 6 rellenadas con 0 a la izquierda, *independientemente* del largo del número o cadena del input.

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza format para retirar la notación científica

> format(1e11, scientific=F)

Y para ejecutar tu función utiliza

> df[1:3,"ID"]<-paste0("0",df[1:3,"ID"])

Nota que los valores a los que se debe asignar sean de la misma longitud del valor que deseas poner

Comment: Y cómo hago para cambiar todo el formato de una columna en particular a scientific=F? He intenado df$variable<-format(df$variable, scientific=F) Y no me funciona. He  usado también options(scipen=999) al inicio del script pero tampoco consigo nada